# Oracle sql case when exclude cells containg string

Tags: sql, oracle

I have this sql query which works well:

```
SELECT distinct
A,
CASE
WHEN Parameter = 'ID' and regexp_like (VALUE, 'FOO')
 THEN VALUE
  ELSE 'NA'
 END AS test FROM my_table;
```

my_table

| A | parameter | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| x | ID | FOO1223 |
| y | ID | FOO5462 |
| z | ID | empy |
| p | ID | BAR5432 |

result:

| A | value |
| --- | --- |
| x | FOO1223 |
| y | FOO5462 |
| z | NA |
| p | NA |

Now I would like to exclude VALUE that starts with 'BAR'. How can I add this to the CASE...WHEN statement?

The output should look this:

| A | value |
| --- | --- |
| x | FOO1223 |
| y | FOO5462 |
| z | NA |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do `NOT LIKE` in the `WHERE` clause to skip the rows where value start with BAR.

```
SELECT distinct
A,
CASE
WHEN Parameter = 'ID' and regexp_like (VALUE, 'FOO')
 THEN VALUE
  ELSE 'NA'
 END AS test FROM my_table
WHERE value NOT LIKE 'BAR%'
```